# Elasticsearch cluster 'master_not_discovered_exception'

Tags: elasticsearch

i have installed elasticsearch 2.2.3 and configured in cluster of 2 nodes

Node 1 (elasticsearch.yml)

```
cluster.name: my-cluster
node.name: node1
bootstrap.mlockall: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com", "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
indices.fielddata.cache.size: "30%"
indices.cache.filter.size: "30%"
node.master: true
node.data: true
http.cors.enabled: true
script.inline: false
script.indexed: false
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

Node 2 (elasticsearch.yml)

```
cluster.name: my-cluster
node.name: node2
bootstrap.mlockall: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com", "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
indices.fielddata.cache.size: "30%"
indices.cache.filter.size: "30%"
node.master: false
node.data: true
http.cors.enabled: true
script.inline: false
script.indexed: false
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

If i get `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state?pretty'` i have:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
      "reason" : null
    } ],
    "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

Into log of node 1 have:

```
[2016-06-22 13:33:56,167][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [node1] new_master {node1}{Vwj4gI3STr6saeTxKkSqEw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-06-22 13:33:56,210][INFO ][http                     ] [node1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2016-06-22 13:33:56,210][INFO ][node                     ] [node1] started
[2016-06-22 13:33:56,221][INFO ][gateway                  ] [-node1] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Into log of node 2 instead:

```
[2016-06-22 13:34:38,419][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [node2] failed to send join request to master [{node1}{Vwj4gI3STr6saeTxKkSqEw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node2][127.0.0.1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[Node [{node2}{_YUbBNx9RUuw854PKFe1CA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=false}] not master for join request]; ]
```

Where the error?

Comment: i checked with netcat and i got
`Ncat: No route to host`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolved with this line:

`network.publish_host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

every `elasticsearch.yml` config file must have this line with your hostname

Comment: has this been changed to `network.host` in recent versions? I am not seeing `network.publish_host` in the `elasticsearch.yml` that ships with `elasticsearch-7.10.1`

Comment: cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.x"]

Comment: @user5359531, `network.publish_host` still exists, but it's an advanced override. It's not necessary if you set `network.host`.

Answer (score 11):

The root cause of `master not discovered` exception is the nodes are not able to ping each other on port 9300. And this needs to be both ways. i.e node1 should be able to ping node2 on 9300 and vice versa.

> Note :  Elasticsearch reserves port 9300-9400 for cluster
>   communication and port 9200-9300 for accessing the elasticsearch APIs.

A simple telnet would be able to confirm. From node1, fire `telnet node2 9300`.

If it succeeds, next from node2 try `telnet node1 9300`.

In case of `master not discovered` exception, at least one of the above telnet would be failing.

In case you don't have telnet installed, you could even do a `curl`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using **elasticsearch 7**

Update `elasticsearch.yml` file at `/etc/elasticsearch` :

```
node.name: "node-1" 

network.host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

http.port: 9200

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```

here `node.name` and first value of `cluster.initial_master_nodes`  should be same

Comment: Seems to work for me (NB with network.host commented-out: localhost only).

Comment: omg! this i s brillant!

Answer (score 6):

This could be reason for master node was not getting discovered. If EC2 instances are under same VPC then please provide Private IP in **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml** as shown below:

`cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["<PRIVATE-IP"]`

Note : After above change in configuration, please restart the elastic search service e.g. **sudo service elasticsearch stop** and **sudo service elasticsearch stop** in case of OS is ubuntu.

Comment: The parameter should contain all the nodes belonging to the cluster. Assuming node-1, node-2 and node-3 are your nodes, here's the setting you can use:

```cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1","node-2","node-3"]```

Comment: Thank's this helps for v7.16 `cluster.initial_master_nodes: [_local_, _site_]`

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of settings in here that you either don't want (like the fielddata one) or don't need. Also, you're clearly using AWS EC2 instances, so you should use the [`cloud-aws` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/cloud-aws-discovery.html) (broken into separate plugins in ES 5.x). This will provide a new discovery model that you can take advantage of instead of `zen`.

For each node, you'll want to therefore install the `cloud-aws` plugin (assuming ES 2.x):

```
$ bin/plugin install cloud-aws
```

Once installed on each node, then you can use it to take advantage of the `discovery-ec2` component:

```
# Guarantee that the plugin is installed
plugin.mandatory: cloud-aws

# Discovery / AWS EC2 Settings
discovery
  type: ec2
  ec2:
    availability_zones: [ "us-east-1a", "us-east-1b" ]
    groups: [ "my_security_group1", "my_security_group2" ]

cloud:
  aws
    access_key: AKVAIQBF2RECL7FJWGJQ
    secret_key: vExyMThREXeRMm/b/LRzEB8jWwvzQeXgjqMX+6br
    region: us-east-1
  node.auto_attributes: true

# Bind to the network on whatever IP you want to allow connections on.
# You _should_ only want to allow connections from within the network
# so you only need to bind to the private IP
node.host: _ec2:privateIp_

# You can bind to all hosts that are possible to communicate with the
# node but advertise it to other nodes via the private IP (less
# relevant because of the type of discovery used, but not a bad idea).
#node:
#  bind_host: [ _ec2:privateIp_, _ec2:publicIp_, _ec2:publicDns_ ]
#  publish_host: _ec2:privateIp_

# Node-specific settings (note: nodes default to be master and data nodes)
node:
  name: node1
  master: true
  data: true

# Constant settings
cluster.name: my-cluster
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Finally, your problem is that you are failing master election for some reason that most likely stems from connectivity issues. The above configuration should fix those issues, but you have one other critical issue: you are specifying the `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` setting incorrectly. You have two *eligible* master nodes, but you are asking Elasticsearch to require *only* one for any election. That means, in isolation, each eligible master node can decide that they have a quorum, and therefore elect themselves separately (thus giving two masters and effectively two clusters). This is **bad**.

You **must** therefore always set that setting using quorum: `(M / 2) + 1`, rounded down, where `M` is the number of master *eligible* nodes. So:

```
M = 2
(2 / 2) + 1 = (1) + 1 = 2
```

If you had 3, 4, or 5 master eligible nodes, then it would be:

```
M = 3
(3 / 2) + 1 = (1.5) + 1 = 2.5 => 2

M = 4
(4 / 2) + 1 = (2) + 1 = 3

M = 5
(5 / 2) + 1 = (2.5) + 1 = 3.5 => 3
```

So, you should also be setting, in your case:

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

Note, you could add this either as another line or, you could modify the discovery block from above (it really comes down to style of YAML):

```
discovery
  type: ec2
  ec2:
    availability_zones: [ "us-east-1a", "us-east-1b" ]
    groups: [ "my_security_group1", "my_security_group2" ]
  zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the info of cloud-aws plugin but now i need use this configuration, i have set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2` but now also the node 1 have the same error of node 2

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use that configuration, but you _probably_ need to fix your `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` lists to use the private IPs of those EC2 instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `changing discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` worked for me. I have used old ES config which had a different `minimum_master_nodes`. corrected it.

Comment: ES >= 8.0: "[_`discovery.zen` settings have been removed. \[...\] All settings under the `discovery.zen` namespace are no longer supported._](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/migrating-8.0.html#breaking_80_cluster_node_setting_changes)"

Answer (score 1):

In my system firewall is on that's why i got same error when i turn off the firewall then every thing is working fine. So make sure that your firewall is off.

Answer (score 1):

If master starts with index made in old version of elastic, and worker start with empty index and init it with new version you can also have this error

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep's answer above hinted to me that nodes aren't able to talk to each other. When I dug more into this, I found that I was missing inbound rule for TCP, port `9300` in EC2's security group. Added the rules and restarted `elasticsearch` service on all nodes and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I used AWS EC2 instances with Centos7.

My issue is that there were no IP routes. I had to open some firewall ports with the instructions below and that solved the problem.

```sh
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9200/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9300/tcp
```