# Elasticsearch: 503 error on cluster - master not discovered

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have set up a cluster with 3 masters for the time being on `AWS`.

Here are the three `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` files

1.`master1`

```
cluster.name: es-staging

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: _ec2:privateIp_
discovery.ec2.endpoint: ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_ip
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2 
node.master: true
s3.client.default.endpoint: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
transport.tcp.port: 9300
node.name: elastic-master1-stg
action.auto_create_index: true
```

2.`master2`

```
cluster.name: es-staging

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: _ec2:privateIp_
discovery.ec2.endpoint: ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_ip
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
node.master: true
s3.client.default.endpoint: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
transport.tcp.port: 9300
node.name: elastic-master2-stg
action.auto_create_index: true
```

3.`master3`

```
cluster.name: es-staging

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: _ec2:privateIp_
discovery.ec2.endpoint: ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_ip
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
node.master: true
s3.client.default.endpoint: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
transport.tcp.port: 9300
node.name: elastic-master3-stg
action.auto_create_index: true
```

However, when on say `master1`:

```
curl -XGET http://10.11.11.118:9200/_cluster/health

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
```

I have installed the `discovery-ec2` plugin

Comment: Did you check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970187/elasticsearch-cluster-master-not-discovered-exception

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it needed a role attached to the instances with the following policy

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```